# Parse| can't save retrieved objects after findInBackground is done

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve String objects from Parse. I do able to get the objects back - but only inside the 'done' method. I wish to send the data i retrieve to another function\class. I tried to do this with some different public function in the same class or even to save the String in public field, but in the moment the callback is done, the data remains blank.

what can i do in order to keep the retrieved data?

this is my code:

```
 public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                'myFieldArray' = new String[parseObjects.size()][3];
                String text = "";

                int index =0;
                for(ParseObject po : parseObjects){
                    text = po.getString("Fact");
                    Toast.makeText(context,theFact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    'myFieldArray'[index][0] = text;
                    index++;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

after few tries, i realized that the Parse query probably goes inside the block twice - and ones when there are no objects returned - thats mean the array will be initialized again - and thats the reason its remains null.

the part i should have added is 
    if (e == null && parseObject.size()>0)